# How can I validate unique field with struts framework and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, struts

I am new in struts2 and hibernate. I want to validate mobile no with data base for uniqueness. How can I validate a unique field with struts framework and hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the validation.

You want to validate to no store some field in DB.

```
// annotations
@NotNull
private Integer someField;


validation api GA in Hibernate validation.
```

Regards.